# How do I use CSS to make my video show through my text?

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I am trying to knockout my text so that the video is showing through, however I have boxes so when ever I hover over "box1", "box2" goes white and has an opacity of 0.5, and they seem to be getting in the way. I want the boxes to do the sam as they are now, just with see through text on top.

Here is my HTML and CSS

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>

<video autoplay muted loop 
       src="car.mp4" 
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</video>
```

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 104vh;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.box1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 814px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 86px;
}

.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
}

.box1:hover + .box2 {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```